# How to read binary file and save to array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, binary

I have a file in csv format look like this:

```
0.0060862,0.31869
0.025889,0.21183
0.064364,0.094135
0.10712,-0.0081176
0.15062,-0.073904
```

I would like to load the first column to array a and second column to array b. This is what the code looks like:

```
double a[5];
double b[5];
int i=0;
FILE* fileHandle = NULL;
fopen_s(&fileHandle, fileName.csv, "r+");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 fscanf_s(fileHandle,"%lf,%lf",a[i],b[i]);
}
fclose(fileHandle);
```

Now I am converting the csv file to a binary file; the data is represented in 2's complement in `unsigned int`. How should I change my code?
I changed the code to

```
unsigned x[5];
unsigned y[5];
double a[5];
double b[5];
int i=0;
FILE* fileHandle = NULL;
fopen_s(&fileHandle, fileName.csv, "rb+");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 fscanf_s(fileHandle,"%u,%u",x[i],y[i]);
 a[i] = x[i]/(2^15);
 b[i] = y[i]/(2^15);
}
fclose(fileHandle);
```

But `x[i]` and `y[i]` read from the binary is always 3435973836. How should I change my code to make it work?

Comment: `"r+"`-->`"rb+"`.

Comment: 2's complement notation is for signed int. To read int from binary file, you can't use a `scanf` like fonction. Something with `fread(&x[i], sizeof(x[i]), 1, fileHandle)` should do the job

Comment: Representing floating point values as unsigned integers is a fraught pastime.  When you show the code that writes the data to the file, there's a decent chance we can guide you on how to read the data.  Until then, your description of "2's complement in `unsigned int`" really doesn't make much sense.  (I'm not sure it'll make sense afterwards, but we may be able to deduce what you mean by it.)

Comment: You must pass the **address** of the targets: `fscanf_s(fileHandle, "%lf,%lf", &a[i], &b[i]);`

Comment: Are you dividing by the constant  (2 xor 15)? Perhaps it should be (1<<15)

Comment: It appears there is a misconception that `(2^15)` is 32768, instead of the actual `13`...

Answer (score 0):

When your data is binary, you don't need to convert it with fprintf and fscanf. 
You can just read and write you array with fread and fwrite.

If your data alternates a and b records, you will better organize your variables the same way :

```
struct ab {
     int a, b;
     } ab[5];
```

and read it all in one shot with

```
fread(ab, sizeof (int), 10, fileHandle);
```

Then process it the way you like.

(see man fread, and man fwrite for details)